# Bootstrap/establish a Spring (+Spring MVC, Security, ...) *SESSION* from a NON-Spring controlling code for further in-thread processing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I need to "marry" two web apps. One is Spring based (let's call that one 'S') and the other one is not (call it 'N'). 'N' must be the controlling one. It must continue (for various reasons) to handle authentication, session establishment and termination, etc. It must serve essentially as a 'host' and a 'wrapper' for 'S'. Specifically, web requests to 'S' may (or not) come *after* login and will go straight from the web container to 'S'. It is also possible that we occasionally need to make a Java call from 'N' code into lower layers of 'S'. This poses two immediate challenges:

1. How to establish a Spring (web) session? We were unsuccessful (for yet unknown reasons, didn't try hard enough, I guess) to use the container's dispatcher to perform a 'slave login' into S during 'N' login. What we presently have working is a sort of a cludge - when 'N' gets a login requests and successfully authenticates the user, it actually creates a true via-the-network HTTP request back to 'self' (that is the same container), directed at a rudimentary login controller of 'S' and uses the same session coookie. I'd like to be able to go more directly (at least via the dispatcher), if not directly to Spring beans somehow. The problem is how to "politely ask Spring" to bootstrap its ThreadLocal context so that its session-related injection works but such that this is not actually coming from the web container - it is coming from 'N's Java code. Since that additional web request is executed on yet-another-thread (as used by the container) we end up using two threads and cannot 'steal' the Spring ThreadLocals either to reuse them later... Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to solve this one?
2. Some requests that 'N' handles require it to gather own data and also get some other data from 'S'. In other words, it has to make Java calls into 'S' code. While we can get access to necessary beans to make the call, this only works if subsequently executed internal to 'S' do not depend on Spring injection (and it does). This is because the thread (at that time) is not set up with necessary context Spring needs to do its injection... and we don't know how to bootstrap that. Our present way is refactoring the 'S' code out and in a way that does not require Spring injection but we don't like doing that for obvious reasons. Can anyone help?

Please note that no answer can involve making 'N' a Spring app or even wrap it into anything Spring. There is no need to even discuss this option.

Thanks in advance!